# git-daemon fails on VM suspend and resume

Tags: process, vmware-server

I have Gitorious running on a Centos 5.3 install on a VMWare virtual machine under VMWare Server. Everytime we take down the server via suspend to back up the image, and resume the VM, the git-daemon dies.

All my other processes continue to function without any problems, this one process dies and has to be manually be restarted.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening, or how to make sure this process never dies off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally got it working reliably, it seems that the `chkconfig` line was trying to start the `git-daemon` process too early in the boot sequence by default. We changed the configuration line in the `/etc/iniit.d` start-up script to `# chkconfig: 2345 99 25` to start absolutely last and it starts and stays started all the time now.

Also, we were having the same problem with the `git-ultrasphinx` process and did the same thing to it and fixed that as well.